# JFrame is not displayed correctly

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, visitor-pattern

In my Client/Server Java application, I found out a strange behaviour, that prevents any content to be displayed in a JFrame than the first one (login one).

The JFrame is diplayed, but it's transparent and if I resize it, I have this effect:

[image]

The application works like this (2 main, 1 in Server class and 1 in Client class:

SERVER SIDE
1) the main has an infinite loop, starting a new thread to handle messages when a client connects to it

CLIENT SIDE
1) the main get the singleton of the GuiLogin JDialog, and execute a method to display it

2) when the user press Login, an ActionListener in the guilogin, invokes the client method to dispatch a LoginRequest object to the Server, that replies with a LoginResponse object

3) if the email and password are correct (email=a,password=b), it should display another JFrame, but whatever i tried, it always displayed the bugged - transparent frame

3b) if the email and password are incorrect, the application displays a JDialog (working fine)

I think my mistake is somewhere conceptual, the code looks right fine, I invoke the new JFrame with

```
   guiLogin.dispose();

   JFrame j = new JFrame();
   j.setVisible(true);
```

as standalone code it works, but inside a method in my Visitor-pattern message handler on the client, it works like in the screenshot

[minified version of the eclipse project, stripped all the class and methods not concerning the bug](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/53684320/RiproduciBug.zip)

EDIT: I am very inexperienced about Java Gui & events, i checked now that the code causing the issue is inside an EDT ( javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread() returns true ). Should i move the whole message handling logic inside a SwingWorker thread?

Comment: the link or the java project? You have to launch both Server and Client

Comment: Seems like you are either blocking your EDT or you not using one at all. I have to wait till morning to see the attached code, since I can not view it on my iPAD :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're blocking `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. Here is a snippet from `TinyClient` that is executed on EDT:

```
do {
    System.out.println("waiting response");
    try {
        Response risp = (Response) in.readObject();
        risp.accept(resHandler);
    }
    catch (SocketException e) {
        // unhandled yet
    }
    Thread.sleep(500);
} while (waitForMessage);
```

On one of the iterations `in.readObject();` call is blocked. Same goes for the `Thread.Sleep`. All UI related work, such as painting, happen on the EDT. Once EDT is blocked it does not process any events. Hence the result you see - the UI is not repainted.

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details. You would want to adopt a multithreaded solution to handle networking. Look into `SwingWorker` in the same tutorial. It allows execution of a task on a background thread and communicate results on EDT thread.

***EDIT***:

As the details and scale of your application are not available it is hard to give a concrete solution. Keep in mind that Swing is single threaded. All UI work must be done on EDT. For best performance, all tasks on EDT should be brief. Networking should be handled on a worker thread. You have several options such as `SwingWorker`, `ExecutorService` or your own auxiliary threads. `SwingWorker` has a built-in mechanism to push updates on EDT. In case of `ExecutorService` you can use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` for that purpose.

Comment: I was already looking those EDT tutorial when Gagandeep Bali hinted that. Edit: i updated my question

Comment: @mark see my last update. you may also choose a dedicated `ExecutorService`.

Comment: I accepted the answer, I think from now on I can figure out. I already fixed it with SwingWorker but I'm still tuning it, since doInBackground() can not be a void function like I'd wish

Comment: Eclipse says "the return type is incompatibile with SwingWorker<Void,Void>" in my protected void doInBackground() method, and the autocorrection hint me to change it to protected Void doInBackground method

Comment: @max +1 for explaining with a small example of how the EDT gets blocked and what needs to be done rather than just saying "`use SwingWorker` or `ExecutorService`"